# Error validating Pod template with NodeSelector

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, nodes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: nginx4
      name: nginx4
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx4
      nodeSelector:
        app: "v1-tesla"
        resources: {}
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Never
    status: {}
```

When I run the above template kubectl create -f pod.yaml, I get the following error:

```
    error: error validating "podOnANode.yaml": error validating data: 
    ValidationError(Pod.spec.nodeSelector.resources): invalid type for 
    io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec.nodeSelector: got "map", expected 
    "string"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off 
    with --validate=false
```

Any pointers to fix this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above error is for:

```
nodeSelector:
  app: "v1-tesla"
  resources: {}
```

Here, `resources: {}` representing `map`, but it should be `string`. So remove `resources: {}` or change it's value to `string`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx4
  name: nginx4
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx4
  nodeSelector:
    app: "v1-tesla"
    resources: "whatever"
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

Comment: Yes that worked !!.. Many Thanks...  Wasn't clear as the line number wasn't mentioned and the focus was on modifying the nodeSelector label and not on resources: {} . But it's always remained empty is it specifically needed for nodeSelector.?